# html5+javascript+css+svg -> android live walpaper , есть ли способ?

Tags: javascript, android

Здравствуйте. 
Есть страничка html5+javascript+css+svg без внешних библиотек. Хочется, чтобы такая страничка отображалась на рабочем столе в android. Переписал отображение на java, работает. Страничку изменил, снова переписывать на java , что совсем не весело. Web-view не работает как live walpaper.
Html5+javascript+css+svg нравится тем, что картинка рисуется скриптом, всё просто, коротко, понятно. В нативный android переделывать - это картинку в jpg/png переводить, логику переписывать, куча сложностей и возни. 
Есть ли способ, как-то транслировать html5+javascript+css+svg в родной код для android или как-то ещё, чтобы на рабочем столе работало? Android 7.0 , совместимость с более ранними версиями неважна.